# How to code with a dropdown list and calculator?

Tags: android, list, dropdown

I'm a beginner in terms of coding and I'm starting a coffee shop business. I need help in coding a simple activity with a dropdown list then using the options in the list to compute for their bill.

This is how I kind of envisioned it happening:

> DROPDOWN LIST OF BEVERAGES
>   DROPDOWN LIST OF NUMBER OF ITEMS (like from 1-10)

then

PRICE OF BEVERAGE * NUMBER OF ITEMS = BILL

Comment: I don't see a valid question here.

Comment: I mean like how do you code this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check how to create How to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example so that you can get a much better response to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You mention in android so I think you want to solution by an android application.
You can create simple android application using android studio and add dropdown list(Spinner) and text field
https://www.androidhive.info/2012/04/android-spinner-dropdown-example/
after getting the values from the dropdown list and text field you should write code to multiplication.